# Data changing with Highcharts point.update

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Edit: Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adnrw/RF7aW/) - slightly different (simplified) code to examples below but same problem.

I have a simple Highcharts bar chart showing two series of data for 2011 (truncated):

```
var dataset = {};

 dataset.attchange2011 = [
    {y: -8.5},
    {y: -8.3}
];
dataset.revchange2011 = [
    {y: -14.9},
    {y: -10.7}
];
```

This is displaying properly in the graph on load:

```
...
 series: [{
   name: 'Change in Revenue',
   data: dataset['revchange2012']
},{
   name: 'Change in Attendance',
   data: dataset['attchange2012']
}]
...
```

I have a second set of data for 2012:

```
 dataset.attchange2012 = [
    {y: 1.2 },
    {y: 14.1}
];
dataset.revchange2012 = [
    {y: 11.5},
    {y: 37.5}
];
```

And a simple function to switch between the years by getting the `data-year` value from a link that's clicked, loop through that year's data and update the series points values, followed by a redraw:

```
...
year = $(this).data('year').toString();
$.each(chart.series[0].data, function (i, point) {
    point.update(dataset['revchange'+year][i], false);
});
$.each(chart.series[1].data, function (i, point) {
    point.update(dataset['attchange'+year][i], false);
});
...
```

The first time the 2011 link is clicked, the data updates correctly. Trying to switch back to 2012 doesn't work.

When looking at each data set at various stages by `console.log(dataset)`, it appears that it is correctly set on page load:

```
dataset 
    Object
        attchange2011: Array[8]
            0: Object
                y: -8.5
        ...
        attchange2012: Array[8]
            0: Object
                y: 1.2
```

But changes when the link is clicked - 2011 values are copied to the 2012 data set:

```
dataset 
    Object
        attchange2011: Array[8]
            0: Object
                y: -8.5
        ...
        attchange2012: Array[8]
            0: Object
                y: -8.5
```

I can't figure out where or why it would be doing that. Any ideas? I am not completely against rewriting everything from scratch if needed.

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code

Comment: @RahulGupta slightly changed code to the examples used but here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adnrw/RF7aW/

Comment: Are you not satisfied with the answer given by ZekeDroid. Is something still missing in his answer that is not according your expectations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by Highcharts. Variables are overwritten when updating points. Instead, use copy of that objects: http://jsfiddle.net/RF7aW/7/

```
series: [$.extend(true, {}, data2013[0]), $.extend(true, {}, data2013[1])],
```

Comment: Please notice that in your fiddle demo, the series names in legends are not updating when changing data from 2013 to 2012 and back forth !

Comment: Neither in demo from question. Also I don't see that issue in the question.. Anyway, to change legend, use `series.update({ name: new_name });`.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! After a little more investigation I noticed that using a third series on load (but not ever switching to it) also solved the problem but your solution is much simpler. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If not against rewriting, I suggest a much cleaner approach which would be this:

Define an actual function, `function makeChart(data)` and initialize it like you do now, giving it the 2012 data. On click of 2012 or 2011 or whatever other button, simply call `makeChart(otherData)`. This extracts the whole updating issue which, by the way, you don't need to iterate through every single point, you can just update the data series entirely with series.update (which I believe redraws anyways).

EDIT:

If not redrawing, try using simple buttons and using series.setData() instead:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/RF7aW/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The aim of updating the points by looping through is to show the transition in data (from one year to the next) for context. Highcharts is pretty simple to destroy and reload with new data, but you lose the context in the process.

Comment: your problem was that data2013 was for some reason being reassinged to be data2012. Printing data2013 and data2012 before clicking your current code, then after and you'll see what i mean